# Создание изображения Java

Tags: java

Можно ли как создать изображение с помощью java? Суть состоит в том, что будет получен многомерный массив чисел, т.е. надо будет вывести матрицу на экран и каждое поле закрасить в определенный цвет.

Или есть другие варианты, например, с помощью HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, например, с помощью BufferedImage. Ему нужно задать в конструкторе необходимые размеры и цветовую модель, затем с помощью метода `setRGB` задать цвет каждого пикселя. Полученное изображение можно либо записать в файл через ImageIO, либо отобразить на экране через Swing или JavaFX.